# What does the "!" symbol at the start of the function do in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was wondering. If this -> `(function(){...})()` is an IIF ( Instantly Invoked Function ) then what does a function like this do -> `!function(){...}`

Comment: In short: the same. There are different ways to write an IIFE.

Comment: `!function(){...}()` (note the final `()`) is another way to write a IIFE as is `+function() {}()`

Comment: So I can write in both ways, correct?

Comment: yes, of course, it's just another notation for effectively the same thing

Comment: Ok thanks! I see someone found an existing post  

Comment: you'll often see `;(function(){...})()` as well ... extra `;` aren't a problem in javascript, but a "missing" one can lead to unexpected results

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224079/discussion-between-user39051323-and-jaromanda-x).